Proving that $\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right) < 0$ leads to concavity
Some added context is that $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$. Also only consider positive $x$.
I am so very close but I fear that either I am missing something or this problem is impossible.
The condition in the title trivially leads to $xf'(x) - f(x) < 0$. I've tried the following:

Let $\phi(x) = xf'(x) - f(x) < 0$ such that $ \phi'(x) = xf''(x) $. Consider $f''(x) > 0 \to \phi'(x) > 0 $. This leads to a contradiction since $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(x) < 0$ for all $x > 0$ but how can $\phi$ increase from 0 to a negative number? This shows that $f''(x) < 0$ but I fear this is only for an interval right after the origin.

If I aim to prove that $f''(x) < 0$ everywhere, it suffices to show that $f''(x) > 0$ on any interval leads to a contradiction. Consider an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f''(x) > 0$, where we have both $f'(a) < f(a)/a$ and $f'(b) < f(b)/b$. Additionally we have $f'(a) < f'(b)$ and $f(a)/a > f(b)/b$. We may construct a delta function $\delta(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} - f'(x)$ to capture the difference. On such an interval $[a,b]$, we can see that $\delta'(x) < 0$ but I do not see any rigorous way to show that it leads to a contradiction such that $\delta(x) < 0$ for some $x \in [a,b]$.


EDIT: I forgot to mention that the function should be twice differentiable, ideally smooth since this problem relates to a physics energy system.

You've assumed that the function is double differentiable which your problem doesn't say.

The following function is a counterexample:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x}, & 0\le x \le 1,
\\
\frac{x^2+3}4, & 1\le x\le \sqrt2,
\\
\frac1{\sqrt2}\tanh(x-\sqrt2)+\frac54,& x\ge \sqrt2.
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to check that (i) $f(0) = 0$, (ii) $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x>0$, and (iii) $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f(x)}{x}\right)<0$ for all $x>0$. However, $f(x)$ is not concave in the interval $1\le x\le \sqrt2$.
Note that $f(x)$ is differentiable, but not twice differentiable. I don't think it's hard to construct a counterexample that is also twice differentiable.

Update: The original question was edited to add the condition that $f(x)$ is twice differentiable. Here's a counterexample for that:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt x, & 0\le x \le 1,
\\
\frac{1}{8} \left(-x^4+6 x^3-13 x^2+16 x\right),& 1\le x \le 2,
\\
\frac{1}{2} \left(2 \sqrt{x-1}+1\right), & x\ge 2.
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to check that $f(x)$ satisfies all the given conditions but it is not concave in a closed interval inside the interval $1\le x \le 2$. In particular, $f''(3/2) > 0$.
I obtained this function by integrating the following function:
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{2\sqrt x}, & 0\le x \le 1,
\\
\frac12 -\frac{1}{16} [(2x-3)^3-(2x-3)],& 1\le x \le 2,
\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}, & x\ge 2.
\end{cases}
$$
Essentially, I chose a decreasing function (here, $\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$), shifted the part of that in $x>1$ by one unit to the right, and fitted a degree-$3$ polynomial in the interval $1\le x \le 2$ so that $f'(x)$ is differentiable. This ensures that $f(x)$ is twice differentiable.
One can replace the polynomial part of $f'(x)$ in the interval $1\le x\le 2$ by a higher degree polynomial so that $f(x)$ is not just twice differentiable but also differentiable $n$ times for any $n\ge 1$.

I was expecting this to be false. I would like to know how you came up with this counter example.

@Nothingspecial the quantity $f(x)/x$ is simply the slope of the line from the origin to $(x,f(x))$. The given condition then means that as we traverse the graph of $f(x)$, this line segment has to keep rotating in the clockwise direction. I figured this should be possible even if $f(x)$ is not concave. This gave me a rough idea of what the shape of the graph of $f(x)$ should be and coming up with explicit example was simply fine-tuning.

@Pranay what a wonderful counterexample! However, I am incredibly curious to see a twice differentiable counterexample. I presented this counter-example to my research advisor and they told me to disregard piece-wise functions. No real explanation why.

As I explained in the above comment, what really matters is the shape of the graph of $f(x)$. I’m sure there’s even a smooth function with that shape. If I find more time later, I’ll think of an explicit example and update the answer.

I added a twice differentiable counterexample. I also explained how you can generate any $n$-differentiable counterexample in this way.
